# Can a loader or some function to run in build time to transform string var in a static string to require() param to him stop to work in dynamic mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, commonjs

I have this code bellow:

```
var m = app.getModuleMetadata(__filename);

module.exports = [m.rota, {
    url: '/costumer/phone/listar',
    templateProvider: function ($q) {
        return $q(function (resolve) {
            require.ensure([], function () {
                resolve(require('../../template/listar.html'));
            });
        });
    },
    controller: m.controller,
    resolve: {
        load: [
            '$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                return $q(function (resolve) {
                    require.ensure([], function () {
                        var modulo = require('../controller/listar.js');
                        $ocLazyLoad.load({ name: modulo.name });
                        resolve(modulo.controller);
                    });
                });
            }
        ]
    }
}];
```

I disire simplify him some thing like:

```
var m = app.getModuleMetadata(__filename);

module.exports = [m.rota, {
    url: '/costumer/phone/listar',
    templateProvider: function ($q) {
        return $q(function (resolve) {
            require.ensure([], function () {
                resolve(require(m.templatePath));
            });
        });
    },
    controller: m.controller,
    resolve: {
        load: [
            '$q', '$ocLazyLoad', function ($q, $ocLazyLoad) {
                return $q(function (resolve) {
                    require.ensure([], function () {
                        var modulo = require(m.controllerPath);
                        $ocLazyLoad.load({ name: modulo.name });
                        resolve(modulo.controller);
                    });
                });
            }
        ]
    }
}];
```

By the way, webpack compile said:

`WARNING in ./modules/costumer/phone/js/rota/listar.js
Critical dependencies:
12:24-35 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./modules/costumer/phone/js/rota/listar.js 12:24-35`

This is because require() function run in a other context, in webpack build context, not in runtime javascript web browser context.

So, require() function needs a static string to give us a expected result.

So, I think... if I create a node function to run before at same context of require() function to resolve string vars?

I know the `__filename` var is in node context like require() function.

I thing in a loader plugin, but I don't know if it work.

Someone else have some idea how can I run a function which run at same context of require() to `resolve(require(m.templatePath));` to give a require param `m.templatePath` a string value?

Thanks in advance.